# file_get_contents() failed to open stream

Tags: php, archivo, servidor, hosting

Lo que necesito es guardar imagen en el servidor remoto que se encuentra en un hosting:

```
$ruta= "C:/wamp64/www/AfuncServidor/imagenes/portadaFacebook.jpg";//aquí el problema que no entiendo.
$imagen = file_get_contents($ruta);

$nombreFoto = substr($ruta, strripos($ruta, "/")+1);
$filepath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."\AfuncServidor\imagenes\\".$nombreFoto;
file_put_contents($filepath,$imagen);
```

cuando la $ruta =  a una ruta del equipo como en la anterior devuelve

> PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(C:/wamp64/www/AfuncServidor/imagenes/portadaFacebook.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in... (archivo.php del servidor)

cuando:

```
$ruta= "https://www.solocruceros.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/shutterstock_79826992.jpg";
```

me funciona, y

```
$ruta = "https://lageografia.com/wp-content/uploads/rio-1.jpg";//tambien no me reconoce con este enlace
```

tampoco me reconoce

Cuál podría ser el problema?  que no pude haber hecho?

PD: La idea es que en un archivo.csv se encuentre una tabla de productos con la ruta de la imagen en una columna. Este archivo.csv pueda ser exportado a una base de datos y el código expuesto anteriormente es donde recibe la ruta que se encuentra en las filas de la tabla de archivo.csv, lo crea la imagen y guarde en el servidor. Espero que me entiendan y me ayuden, desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: No entiendo. Si es un servidor remote, ¿qué hace esto en la ruta `"C:/`?

Comment: Y... me parece que tienes que habilitar `allow_url_fopen` en el archivo `php.ini` si quieres cargar archivos desde una URL exterior [ver el Manual para más detalles](http://php.net/manual/es/filesystem.configuration.php). Pero ten cuidado haciendo eso, la seguridad de tu servidor podría verse seriamente afectada.

Comment: A. Cedano, la imagen se encuentra en `C:/...` éste tomo y quiero subir al servidor remoto. Tomando la imagen que se encuentra en `C:/..`no me funciona (es lo que quiero que funcione), en cambio si lo tomo de otras url externa me lo guarda sin problema a mi servidor

Comment: ¿No habrás emprendido un camino errado? Creo que deberías usar `move_uploaded_file` y cargar el archivo local desde un formulario... ¿cómo tu servidor remoto va a reconocer una ruta que está en tu equipo local?

Comment: En teoría en `$imagen = file_get_contents($ruta);` se genera la imagen apartir de la ruta dada (del equipo) y con `file_put_contents($filepath,$imagen);` sube al servidor. Me da este error ´failed to open stream: No such file or directory' cuando la ruta es ´C:/...` pero cuando la ruta es `http://www.example.com/cualquierimagen.jpg` me funciona sin problema, eso lo que es raro.