# Problemas con file_get_contents()

Tags: php, webservice, php5, servidor

Estaba haciendo las pruebas en un servidor local (localhost) con Wampp, en la cual me funcionaba perfecto lo siguiente, que me guardaba la imagen copiada de la ruta dada a otra carpeta del servidor local. En ese momento los script tenía en la pc (wampp)

```
$imagen = file_get_contents('C:\Users\JoelR-FCA-ADM\Pictures\Cena Show\1.jpg');
file_put_contents('$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] ."/AfuncServidor/imagenes/1.jpg', $imagen);
```

cuando los scripts lo subí a mi servidor hosting de pago ya no me funciona con la ruta `'C:\Users\JoelR-FCA-ADM\Pictures\Cena Show\1.jpg'` solo me funciona con imagenes externas, o sea con ruta como ´https://www.ecestaticos.com/imagestatic/clipping/94c/b1d/94cb1d7e38922d4c6abde324c98ad3cb/el-lado-oculto-de-los-cruceros-codigos-secretos-piratas-y-contaminacion.jpg?mtime=1502286840` sí funciona.. 
Pero lo que necesito es que me funcione con la ruta interna de mi pc, para que el usuario pueda subirlo.
Alguien me puede decir, por qué me funciona en la computadora y en el servidor no? sería por el sistema operativo que usa el servidor? que me supongo Linux.

el error que da es

> failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Comment: ¿En tu servidor de hosting tienes el path C:\Users\JoelR-FCA-ADM\Pictures\Cena Show\1.jpg?

Comment: el path  C:\Users\JoelR-FCA-ADM\Pictures\Cena Show\1.jpg es de mi computadora. el script se encuentra en el servidor

Comment: Independientemente del sistema operativo pueda ser diferente, estás corriendo un script en el servidor remoto con el que quieres que se abra una ruta local de tu computadora. El servidor la va a intentar abrir la ruta como local, no va a encontrarla y va a dar el fallo que ves.

Comment: Por cierto, ¿no hiciste esta pregunta hace unas horas? Lee [ask] y no dupliques contenido. ¿Cómo es esta pregunta diferente a [file_get_contents() failed to open stream](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/178803/250)?

Comment: De acuerdo, lo tendré en cuenta. Muchas gracias por su respuesta, lo cambiaré la manera de subir el archivo. Comentaré lo que quería hacer: que el usuario cree una tabla en Excel con caracteristicas del producto con la ruta de las respectivas imágenes, luego lo convierte en formato archivo.csv de tal maneta a importar a la base de datos del servidor y subir la imagen de la computadora. Pues ahora lo pensaré otra manera de subir.